# data set of family trees in GEDCOM format?

Tags: data-request

Are there any [GEDCOM files](https://github.com/FamilySearch/gedcomx/blob/master/specifications/conceptual-model-specification.md) of family trees freely available?

It should be of real persons, not artificial data.

The genealogy of famous people or very big family trees that go back in history would be especially interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [option to download GEDCOM family trees](http://www.wikitree.com/wiki/Special:DownloadGedcom) on the [WikiTree](http://www.wikitree.com) genealogy website. No member can request more than six files per day. Repeatedly requesting six files per day is also prohibited.

I've just tested it with the family tree of Elvis Presly (WikiTree ID `Presley-155`), it took a while to compile it and I was informed by email when the file was ready for download. It looks quite extensive (the GEDCOM file has more than 35000 lines).

I couldn't find any license information.